# Unsupervised clustering in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, cluster-analysis

I have written a script in pycharm for Unsupervised clustering. I wanna know why pycharm does give me this error. I know there is an argument missing but how should I correct it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/Python/Projects/Kmeans.Clustering.py", line 36, in <module>
y_Kmeans = KMeans.fit_predict(points)
TypeError: fit_predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

And this is my code:

```
    import tensorflow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

## 1. Generate Dataset
dataset = make_blobs(n_samples=200,
                     centers=4,
                     n_features=2,
                     cluster_std=1.6,
                     random_state=50)

print(dataset)
points = dataset[0] # First array which is the Points ( X,Y Coordinates)

#print(points)

# 2. Import KMEANS

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)       # As specified for Center of Cluster

# 3. Begin the Lloyd algorithm for This Dataset
kmeans.fit(points)

# 4. Plot the dataSet
plt.figure(1)
plt.scatter(dataset[0][:,0],dataset[0][:,1])
plt.show()

# 5. Create and Print Clusters

Clusters = kmeans.cluster_centers_       # Which will give us the Centers of the Clusters which are found by the Kmeans Algorithm
print(Clusters)

y_Kmeans = KMeans.fit_predict(points)
plt.scatter(points[y_Kmeans==0,0],points[y_Kmeans==0,1],s=50,edgecolors='red')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the brackets:

```
y_Kmeans = KMeans().fit_predict(points)
```